# Gerar gráficos em imagem

Tags: node.js

Tem alguma api onde eu passo os dados, e ela me retorna o link de uma imagem com o gráfico gerado, em node js?

Achei esse projeto: https://github.com/ryanrolds/quiche, mas parece estar desatualizado, será que vale a pena usá-lo?

Comment: Você pode ver de fazer por processing , tem vários experimentos muito interessantes para gráficos.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Já vi este mas não tenho certeza se é o que busca e também nunca testei. Tem documentação legível. [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)